# White flashes during page loads on Prestashop

Tags: html, css, prestashop

For some reason the website flashes white DURING (not in the beginning) of every page load.

First some the page seems to load fine (almost completely) but then there's a flash and only after that all of the elements are shown.

I tried implementing [this](http://tr1.cbsistatic.com/hub/i/r/2013/10/17/93a415d1-83a2-41c5-b3d3-7a66b5c99ed1/resize/620x485/FOUC_FigB_101713.gif?hash=7d970217c0dcfbe2c69d415b63278e8b) to fix it but now only the background image is shown after which there is a white flash.

Any idea what's causing these flashes and what should I do to fix them?

[Web site](https://www.hersecret.fi).
The same thing happens on all the pages on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Well actually I figured it out myself. I had the visualwebsiteoptimizer code near the bottom of the body when it needs to be in the head. That's what was causing those weird flashes.

-Petteri